# Использование стороннего компилятора clang на macOS для Qt qmake

Tags: c++, qt, xcode, macos, qmake

Мне надо собрать проект C++ Qt. У меня установлен llvm-8, в pro-файле указанно

```
CONFIG += C++14
```

В Qt добавлен компилятор и создан комплект с этим компилятором.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако при генерации Makefile я получаю

```
CXX           = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -O2 -std=gnu++11 $(EXPORT_ARCH_ARGS) -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -Wall -W -fPIC $(DEFINES)
LINK          = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
```

Как мне побороть то что qmake при генерации Makefile ссылается на компилятор в XCode и устанавливает версию С++11?

Comment: При этом наиболее интересный вопрос, почему, несмотря на то что указанный в pro-файле стандарт ++14, в makefile он ++11.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка с стандартом оказалась результатом банальной невнимательности.
Вместо

```
CONFIG += C++14
```

Надо указывать

```
CONFIG += с++14
```

Из-за верхнего регистра флаг игнорировался и выставлялся дефолтный стандарт ++11